# my laravel controllers and routes not working except the default route of breeze auth package

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, vuejs3, breeze

I don't know why when I add a normal route like this it does not work :

```
Route::resource('produits', ProduitsController::class);
```

just  the default route that comes with breeze package works :

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
            return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
        })->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

so only the get route works ,but I can't access to the controllers and the functions
I'm stuck with that for many days,I don't even have errors to know what is the problem exactly ,
it's my first time working with breeze and I'm also new to laravel,please help me .

I've read breeze documentation and follow the same steps .

Comment: Can you give more details about "it does not work"? Are you seeing an error? Could you share the code in your `ProduitsController` class?

Comment: Assuming that you have created the ProductsController, have you correctly imported the Products Controller in web.php?